# Write PHP logs in my application log file

Tags: php, logging, error-handling

I'm developing a php application and I have created logging feature for it. I mean everytime that something wents wrong I write it in my log file so if an user reports a bug, I can use my log file to trace that bug.

The problem is that if I upload my project on production server, I have to disable PHP's default error display; I just want to log php errors inside my own log file alongside of webserver's 'error.log'. Is there any way so I can do that?

Comment: If you just turn error_reporting off, php errors should still write to the apache error.log file.

Comment: @Jonathan I know that, but I want php to write errors in my own log file too.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: @Jonathan I think it's what I need. I'll try it asap.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I think changing the error handler is the best solution I've found. Will you write it as answer to my question so I can mark it as correct answer?!

Comment: You can actually enable logging for your app and specify where. Here's a brief overview of how - https://blog.phplogger.com/2019/03/18/log-files-in-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For FEATURED USABLE EXCEPTIONS (i'm calling full featured usable exceptions, (without stack trace)):

Set if you are developer to:

```
   define('EXCEPTION_HANDLER_ACTIVE', true);
```

In production this will also should be to true, but modified of code to not show errors on end users. (use: `error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors', false)` on top of page));

First set main function for handling exceptions:

```
set_error_handler("_handler_exception");
```

Function for calling handler of exception:

```
function _handler_exception($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_filepath, $err_line)
    {
        if (EXCEPTION_HANDLER_ACTIVE == 1)
        {
            $eh = new exceptionhandler;

            $eh->exception_active = true;
            $eh->set_exception_handler_log($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_filepath, $err_line);
        }
        else
        {
            $eh = new exceptionhandler;

            $eh->exception_active = false;
            $eh->set_exception_handler_log($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_filepath, $err_line);
        }
    }
```

Class exceptionhandler:

```
class exceptionhandler
{
    public $exception_active = true;

   public function set_exception_handler_log($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_filepath, $err_line)
    {        
    $ret_err_severity = NULL;
    $ret_err_no = NULL;
    $ret_info = NULL;
    $filenameerr = NULL;
    $dbout = NULL;

    switch ($err_severity)
    {
        case E_ERROR:
            $ret_err_severity = "E_ERROR"." [ ".$err_severity." ]";
            $ret_err_no = "1";
            $ret_info = "Fatal run-time errors. These indicate errors that can not be recovered from, such as a memory allocation problem. Execution of the script is halted.";
            $ret_err_msg = $err_msg;
            break;

        case E_STRICT:
            $ret_err_severity = "E_STRICT"." [ ".$err_severity." ]";
            $ret_err_no = "2048";
            $ret_info = "Enable to have PHP suggest changes to your code which will ensure the best interoperability and forward compatibility of your code. ";
            $ret_err_msg = $err_msg;
            break;
        default:
            $ret_err_severity = "CODE"." [ ".$err_severity." ]";
            $ret_err_no = $err_severity;
            $ret_info = "Other error";
            $ret_err_msg = $err_msg;
            break;
    }

    $ef = explode("/", $err_filepath);
    $ec = (count($ef) - 1);
    $filenameerr = $ef[$ec];

    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();

    if (!isset($doc_root)) {
        $doc_root = str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    }

    $debug_backtrace_parse = print_r(debug_backtrace(), true);
    $debug_backtrace2 = str_replace($err_msg, '<b>'.$err_msg.'</b>', $debug_backtrace_parse);
    $debug_backtrace = str_replace($err_filepath, '<b>'.$err_filepath.'</b>', $debug_backtrace2);

    $line = (isset($backtrace[1]['line'])) ? htmlspecialchars($backtrace[1]['line']) : '';
    $file = (isset($backtrace[1]['file'])) ? htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array('\\', $doc_root), array('/', ''), $backtrace[1]['file'])) : '';
    $class = !empty($backtrace[2]['class']) ? htmlspecialchars($backtrace[2]['class']) . '::' : '';
    $function = !empty($backtrace[2]['function']) ? htmlspecialchars($backtrace[2]['function']) . '() ' : '';
    $dbout = "<pre>$class$function =&gt;$file #$line</b><pre>";

    $memory = memory_get_usage()/1024/1024;

    if ($this->exception_active == true)
    {
        $source_highlight = $this->source_highlight($file, $backtrace);

        ob_start();
        include_once(exception.tpl);
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $buffer;
        exit(-1);
    }
    }
```

Exception.tpl

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title><?php echo $ret_err_severity; ?> | <?php echo $filenameerr; ?></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#errorhandlerexception
        {
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
            background-color: #ff9999;
            width: 96%;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #000;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 10px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        div#errorhandlerexception h2
        {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        div#errorhandlerexception td
        {
            background-color: #ffcccc;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 3px;
        }
        div#errorhandlerexception .main
        {
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        div#errorhandlerexception
        {
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }
        .linenum
        {
            text-align:right;
            background:#FDECE1;
            border:1px solid #cc6666;
            padding:0px 1px 0px 9px;
            float:left;
            width:25px;
            margin:3px 0px 30px 0px;
            font-family: Courier New, Courier;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
        .code
        {
            font-family:Courier New, Courier;
            font-size: 11px;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .linetext
        {
            width:95%;
            text-align:left;
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #cc6666;
            border-left:0px;
            padding:0px 1px 0px 8px;
            font-family: Courier New, Courier;
            float:left;
            margin:3px 0px 30px 0px;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
        br.clear
        {
            font-family:Courier New, Courier;
            clear:both;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
        #exception_selected_block
        {
            background-color: #ffff00;
        }
        div.exception_filename
        {
            border-left: 19px solid #AA7777;
            border-top: 3px solid #AA7777;
            color: #000000;
            float: left;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 6px;
            width: 98%;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

<body>
<div id="errorhandlerexception"><?php #echo $msg; ?>
<h2>EXCEPTION ERROR HANDLER</h2>
<table>
    <tr><td class="main">Status:</td><td><?php echo $ret_err_severity; echo " #".$err_severity; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="main">Debug stack:</td><td><?php echo $dbout; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="main">Code:</td><td><?php echo $ret_err_no; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="main">Message:</td><td><?php echo $ret_err_msg; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="main">Info:</td><td><?php echo $ret_info; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="main">File:</td><td><?php echo $filenameerr; ?><br><?php echo $err_filepath; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="main">Line:</td><td><?php echo $err_line; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="main" colspan="2"><?php echo $source_highlight; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="main">Debug backtrace:</td><td><pre><?php echo $debug_backtrace; ?></pre></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom error handler to do your own logging inside of php. This also would allow you to log to a database (assuming the error isn't db related and you have a valid connection) or to a flat-file based on the error and also setup custom error pages. see:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 1):

you can use set_error_handler to define your own function, which is invoked in case of error.

```
<?php
//error handler function
function customError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
  {
  echo "<b>Custom error:</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />";
  echo " Error on line $errline in $errfile<br />";
  echo "Ending Script";
  die();

//set error handler
set_error_handler("customError");

$test=2;

//trigger error
if ($test>1)
  {
  trigger_error("A custom error has been triggered");
  }
?>
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_set_error_handler.asp